# Which tags are mandatory in R documentation?

Tags: r

When documenting R functions in a `myfunction.Rd` and whole packages 
in a `mypackage-package.Rd`, which tags are compulsory?

By "tags", I mean those things that look like `\somename{}`. For example:
`\item{}`
`\title{}`
`\examples{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described in [Section 2.1 - Rd format](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Rd-format) of Writing R Extensions.  Look for "mandatory".

For functions, the mandatory sections are:

```
\name{name}
\alias{topic}
\title{title}
\description{...}
\usage{fun (arg1, arg2, ...)}
\arguments{...}
```

For packages:

```
\name{name}
\alias{topic}
\title{title}
\docType{package}
```